# Is there a Property for the array of el-table-column in el-table

Tags: element-ui

Looking at the documentation for ElementUI table here: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table there is no evidence of a property for the array / collection of columns.

In elementUI table there is the data property to bind the data array but I want to do something similar with the el-table-column array.

What I want is to be able to add columns in a way similar to the way bootstrap-vue does it by being able to bind a separate array of column configuration to the table.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a codepen for this. Hope this helps someone in the future.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgdKzm

Since the functionality is not available by default, we have to write a bit of custom code. Basically you assume the first row always contains the header.

```
const tableData = [
            ['Date', 'Name', 'Address'],
            ['2016-05-03', 'Tom', 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles1'], 
            ['2016-05-02', 'James', 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles2'],
            ['2016-05-03', 'Alice', 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles3'], 
            ['2016-05-02', 'John', 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles4']
          ]

<el-table
      border
      :data="tableData.slice(1)">
      <!--Assuming the first row always contains the table header-->
      <el-table-column
        v-for="(column, index) in tableData[0]"
        :key="index
        :label="column">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          {{ scope.row[index] }}
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
```

The slice function will return a new array without modifying the original array and we can iterate and render custom content using the slot-scope.

Comment: as slot-scope is obsolete, it'd be: `template v-slot="scope">{{ scope.row[index</template>`